# How to make a Sharepoint Survey window open on page load

Tags: sharepoint, modal-dialog

I've been working on looking for an answer to this issue for several days. I've created a survey on a Sharepoint 2010 site, and the person who I made it for wants it to open in a modal window on page load, instead of having to click "Respond to Survey" for this to happen.

I've tried multiple javascript based solutions, and so far I've gotten nothing. Is there any way to do this? And, if there is, is it possible that this solution could be ported to other pages, so that I can make other surveys or other sharepoint pages open in a modal window (on page load) instead of on a separate page?

Comment: ant you just open the survey page in a modal window?

Answer (score 2):

Use .../yoursite/lists/yoursurvey/NewForm.aspx - It seems the Advanced setting "use open forms in dialog" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this for a policy window. I made the whole thing inside of a content editor webpart which basically in invisible because the code has no appearence and I set the chrome type to none.

The other option is a feature which would replace the masterpage which is also not hard but requires a developement system for VS2010.

For the first method mentioned. You may have to strip the cookie stuff if you want it to load every time.
Create a new Content Editor Web Part with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="disclaimer.js"></script>
```

Then create disclaimer.js:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("initialDisclaimerSetup");

var dialogTitle = "";
var dialogBody = "";
var dialogReturn = "";
var userID = _spUserId;

function initialDisclaimerSetup() {
    if(getCookie("DisclaimerShown" + userID) == "Yes") {
        return;
    } else {
        setCookie("DisclaimerShown" + userID, "No", 365);
    }

    getDisclaimerListItems();
}

function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, numExpireDays) {
    var expirationDate = new Date();
    expirationDate.setDate(expirationDate.getDate() + numExpireDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";" +
        "expires=" + ((numExpireDays == null) ? "" : expirationDate.toUTCString());
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
    if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
        return document.cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

function getDisclaimerListItems() {
    var listName = "Disclaimer";

    var soapEnv = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
        + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
        + "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
        + "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\/\">"
        + "<soap:Body>"
        + "<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">"
        + "<listName>" + listName + "</listName>"
        + "<query><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /></IsNotNull></Where></Query></query>"
        + "<ViewFields><ViewFields>"
        + "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Disclaimer\"/>"
        + "</ViewFields></ViewFields>"
        + "</GetListItems>"
        + "</soap:Body>"
        + "</soap:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        complete: processResult
    });
}

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        dialogTitle = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        dialogBody = $(this).attr("ows_Disclaimer");
        launchModelessDialog();

        if(dialogReturn == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if(dialogReturn == 1) {
        } else if(dialogReturn == 2) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(dialogReturn == 0) {
        getDisclaimerListItems();               
    } else if(dialogReturn == 1) {
        setCookie("DisclaimerShown" + userID, "Yes", 365);
    } else if(dialogReturn == 2) {
        window.close();
    }
}

function GetRootUrl() {
    var urlParts = document.location.pathname.split("/");
    urlParts[urlParts.length - 1] = "";
    return "https://" + document.location.hostname + urlParts.join("/");
}

function launchModelessDialog(){
    if (window.showModalDialog) {
        window.showModalDialog("./disclaimer.htm", window, "dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:700px");
    } else {
        objPopup = window.open("./disclaimer.htm", "popup1", "left=100,top=100,width=800,height=800,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, modal=yes");
        objPopup.focus();
    }
}
```

Then create disclaimer.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialRun() {
        //var allArgs = dialogArguments;
        var dialogTitle = dialogArguments.dialogTitle;
        var dialogBody = dialogArguments.dialogBody;
        dialogArguments.dialogReturn = "0";

        document.getElementById('mainWrapper').innerHTML = "<h1>" + dialogTitle + "</h1>"
            + "<br/>" + dialogBody + "<br/><br/>";
    }

    function returnYes() {
        dialogArguments.dialogReturn = 1;
        window.close();
    }

    function returnNo() {
        dialogArguments.dialogReturn = 0;
        window.close();
    }

    function returnClose() {
        dialogArguments.dialogReturn = 2;
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialRun()">
<div id="mainWrapper">
</div>
<div align="center">
    <input name="acceptTOS" type="button" value="I Accept" onClick="returnYes();" />
    <input name="acceptTOS" type="button" value="I Do NOT Accept" onClick="returnNo();" />
    <input name="acceptTOS" type="button" value="Close" onClick="returnClose();" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create a new Custom List called 'Disclaimer' and add a new column called 'Disclaimer' which allows for free text.